# How to make an installer in VB.NET which can install SQL Server Express Edition?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

How can I make an installer in VB.NET which can install [SQL Server Express Edition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Express)?

Comment: be more specific? do you want to install your `vb.net` application along with `sql server` or you want to make a custom installer in `vb.net` to install `sql server`  ??

Comment: @hector I wants to install vb.net application with sql server.I means when I install vb.net app then sql server should be also install in machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not 100% clear, but...

You can try Prerequisites:

[image]

Else you need [InstallShield](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InstallShield) 2013, Limited Edition. Go to http://learn.flexerasoftware.com/content/IS-EVAL-InstallShield-Limited-Edition-Visual-Studio and download it for free. Register and get the key. It's free :)