# How to deploy VB.net application that uses VS Studio for desktop 2012 and MS SQL Server Management Studio 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, deployment

I'm actually done doing the small-scale application for our office, however, I really don't have any idea how to deploy this one. Can someone provide me any links on how to do this? This project will be deployed in one pc.

Comment: this could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158337/how-to-make-an-installer-in-vb-net-which-can-install-sql-server-express-edition/24166687#24166687

Answer (score 0):

If its a Windows application you need to create a [setup project](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/cb88b2/simple-steps-to-create-setup-file-using-install-shield-le-fr/).

If its a web based application, install your application on your web server and provide clients with the appropriate link.

Comment: I didn't mention that I'm using VS Express for Desktop 2012 and according to my research, Express does not support InstallShield..do you have any other options available/

Comment: Please check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12378125/create-msi-or-setup-project-with-visual-studio-2012), hope it will help