# How to build a project in VS12 with DB in SQL Server2012

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I have developed a vb.net project in VS12 with DB in SQL Server 2012. I need to publish it as .exe or .msi file. But I can't do so in VS2012 ultimate. During publishing, it shows an error

> " System.InvalidOperationException the connection string has not  been
>   initialized"

Database(.mdf) is in the root folder of sql server.It is accessible when running in VS2012.When I build the project,I don't know how to link database with the exe. I don't know how to make exe or msi package with database on local machine. Please help me to build my vb.net project to exe with database.

Comment: So you are trying to include DB as part of the installer EXE, or as part of the actual program EXE, or both?

Comment: you can try InstallShield  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158337/how-to-make-an-installer-in-vb-net-which-can-install-sql-server-express-edition/24166687#24166687

Comment: I want to create an exe or msi of the vb.net project. It is having login etc etc. So I want to add the database to the installation folder and access it through installed software(exe /msi) so that the login, insertion,deletion and updation can work without errors.  @Neolisk

Comment: I have already done that. But I couldn't add database to the installation folder. I got errors. @Creator

Comment: @Midhun: So the DB would be a separate file after install? Do you plan to also install SQL Server as part of your installer, or is it installed already? Please add more details to your question, even if it's just based on your replies to our questions in comments.

Comment: I want to create an exe or msi of the project. The database should be in the installation folder.All I want is the proper working of queries(through software).no need to install SQL server. Just publish as exe or MSI and it should access the db without error. @Neolisk

Comment: @Neolisk    : The comment by city0666 is my problem. I want the same.Please help me..

Comment: 1.The project should be built. 2.after built,files should be copied to specified installation folder when installing(including database). 3. after install,software should work well(without any connection error).  @Neolisk

Comment: Check this out - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16231/Deploy-your-Application-and-Database and then see if you can implement something like this using InstallShield. I understand that setup project has been decommissioned starting with VS 2012.