# How to implement SQL Database as a packaged software with VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2012, deployment

E.g. Customer downloads the setup from my website and install the required pre-requisites. That's it. It is ready to use. I want this. How to implement this.

On my developer machine, i create all the database, tables, views, sample data for testing. But i want to implement a fresh copy of same DB on customer machine while he installs or runs my application. Help me, what is correct practice of doing this?

Language : VB.NET
SQL : SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: maybe this could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158337/how-to-make-an-installer-in-vb-net-which-can-install-sql-server-express-edition/24166687#24166687. Download installschield

Comment: This is just about installing SQL Server. I want this : "I have this Database on my developer machine whre i test the demo data, how to implement a blank fresh DB on the customer end"

Comment: With installschield you have a lot of options you can use to make a installer.i never tried to add a db file but just check it.maybe its what you need . "just saying"

Comment: ^Creator : Tried, that didn't work :/

Comment: last question .is this a single computer app?if yes is there a special rezone you use SQL Server 2008 R2? if no did you ever try SqlLocalDB ?

Comment: @Creator The app works in multi-user environment :/