# VB.net & SQL database deployment as setup project

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, installation

The thing is I have developed a VB.net Project (Win application) and it's connected to database (SQL SERVER) .. What I did I create setup using setup shield

Then, I've published a sql server database using this link 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2007/10/15/sql-database-publishing-wizard-is-now-in-visual-studio-orcas.aspx

and I've got the file

I want this project to work on other machine as setup or exe file ... Is there any help?

Comment: Do you just want some kind of executable to publish the database? Or are you looking to publish the database *and* your VB.NET project?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make an installer in VB.NET which can install SQL Server Express Edition?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158337/how-to-make-an-installer-in-vb-net-which-can-install-sql-server-express-edition)

Comment: yes dear I'm looking to publish both database and vb.net